# телеграм чат бот кнопки

Tags: python, pycharm, telebot

```
Пишу телеграм бот на библиотеке телеграм бот айпи.
```

Хочу создать кнопки. Бот выводит стартовое сообщение , а кнопок нет .
Пишу в pyCharm . Код с зеленой галкой. Не понимаю почему не высвечиваются кнопки. В коде они же прописаны.
Помогите!! Может кто-то поделится какой-то базовой информацией по созданию этих кнопок. Пожалуйста.

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привіт, друже! Чей Чат-бот допоможе тобі разрахувати конкурсний бал.")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Привет', 'Пока')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!', reply_markup=keyboard)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#reply-markup

Answer (score 1):

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('a')
itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('v')
itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('d')
markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3)  # забыли add
tb.send_message(chat_id, "Choose one letter:", reply_markup=markup)
```